# Trouble understandingthat the special set $\mathbb{B}$ has the following properties

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, minimal-polynomials

Let $\mathbb{B}:=\{\alpha\in\mathbb{C}|$The minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ lies in $\mathbb{Z}[x]\}$

In my notes for Algebraic number theory it's proven that the set $\mathbb{B}$ has the following properties:

*$\mathbb{B}$ is a ring: I understand this part of the proof in my notes

*$\mathbb{B}\cap\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Z}$: Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{B}\cap\mathbb{Q}$. The minimum polynomial of $\alpha, f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]\iff\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence $\mathbb{B}\cap\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Z}$. In this proof I don't really understand the iff, where do we use the fact that $\alpha$ is also in $\mathbb{Q}$.

*All conjugates of $\alpha\in\mathbb{B}$, lie in $\mathbb{B}$. Here a conjugate is an element with the same minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$: I understand this part of the proof in my notes

Comment: My Warwick algebraic number theory course seems to be all over math.SE at the moment. You could just come to my office hour -- I'm being paid to teach you this stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$ if and only if its minimal polynomial  (over $\mathbb{Q}$) is of degree $1$ (so it is $X - \alpha$).

Comment: oh so since $\alpha\in\mathbb{B}$ we want this min poly to be in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. It's min poly over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is $x-\alpha$, which can only be in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ if $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Yes. That's it.